# Possible to scroll caret into view inside a single HTML text field with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textbox

Knowing the [jQuery Caret plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret), I'm still seeing no way to do the following on a single line text box in HTML (i.e. the `input:type=text` control) with JavaScript:

1. Programmatically inserting text into a text box
2. Setting the caret to the end.
3. **Making the caret visible** (i.e. scroll the text box content)

I know how to do 1. and 2., just for 3. I have found no way of doing it.

To illustrate it:

[image]

**My question is:**

Is there any way to reliable put the caret at the end of the text *and* scroll it into the view?

(I can think of simulating pressing the `END` key or something like that, but I'm unsure whether this would be the best option).

Comment: The accepted answer does not work cross-browser. I've successfully tested it in Chrome 14, but it failed in FireFox 3.6.23

Comment: Thanks, @Rob i'll check this out. Tested on ff 4 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//hack to get cursor at end:

```
$(textboxselector).val($(textboxselector).val());
```

edit: should note focus first:

```
$(textboxselector).val(newtext);
$(textboxselector).focus();
$(textboxselector).val($(textboxselector).val());
```

Comment: Gettint the caret at the end is easy. The OP wants the caret to be *visible* though, which is not the case with this solution. Also, you've got a typo and an undefined variable in your code. http://jsfiddle.net/xEcup/

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks, yes it is an example/start not a "full" solution. Seems to work for me (jsfiddle NOT working in all browsers at the moment though) http://jsbin.com/itapeq/2/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: it is the call to .focus() that scrolls to the end - I would expect this to work with only the first two lines: `$(textboxselector).val(newtext);
$(textboxselector).focus();`

Answer (score 3):

You could try triggering a right key press after focus.

```
$('#textbox').focus();
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 39; // aka right arrow.
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Tried this in Google Chrome and was unable to get any scrolling or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's **not** possible to implement this behavior cross-browser. FireFox supports the [`KeyboardEvent.initKeyPress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initKeyEvent) method, which allows key events to be simulated.

See the comments at the function below for an explanation. I've successfully tested this function in FireFox 3.6.22, 7.0.1 and Chrome 14.

The function itself is plugin-independent. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jskbb/1/**

```
/* @name caretAtEnd
 * @description Places caret at the end
 * @param elem  DOM element
 * @param focus boolean, optional. If true, the element will be focused.
 */
function caretAtEnd(elem, focus){
    var value = elem.value;

    //Add an extra character to the input field (necessary for this method)
    // An additional advantage is that the caret automatically moves to the end
    elem.value = elem.value + ".";

    try {
        // Create and simulate/trigger a [Backspace] keypress event.
        var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
        evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", 1, 1, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0);
        elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } catch(e){
        //The current key event is not supported yet. Change back the value
        // In some browsers, the caret is at the end after executing this code.
        elem.value = value;
    }

    //Optionally, Focus on the element
    if(focus) elem.focus();
}

var element = $("#yourInputElement")[0]; //Important: Get the DOM element!
caretAtEnd(element);
```

Comment: If I try your solution in Chrome in JSFiddle, I get an error `"TypeError: Object #<KeyboardEvent> has no method 'initKeyEvent' [http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display:25]"`.

Comment: @UweKeim "FireFox supports the ...". Oops. At my last edit, I accidentally removed **"not"** at "... possible to support this behavior cross-browser." Currently, there's no cross-browser method to implement this feature in JavaScript.

Comment: interesting approach that might work with some update as "The initKeyEvent method is only supported by Firefox. In Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer from version 9, use the initKeyboardEvent method instead. In Internet Explorer before version 9, use the createEventObject method to create a new event object and the fireEvent method to dispatch it. "

Comment: @UweKeim I've added a try-catch block. When the method isn't supported yet, the value is changed back. The updated answer supports more browsers, including **Chrome**.

Answer (score 2):

So with the [help of Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/possible-to-scroll-caret-into-view-inside-a-single-html-text-field-with-javascri/7903519#7903519) and [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w), I finally managed to solve it.

My additional challenge was that the text box already *has* the focus, which came out is an issue (I'm using the whole stuff in the `OnClientItemSelected` of the [Ajax Toolkit's `AutoCompleteExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx)).

So my solution is:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="EMailTextBoxControlAutoCompleteExtender" 

    ...

    OnClientItemSelected="function() { 
        // Read current text and append some string.
        var tbSel = '#EMailTextBoxControl';
        var newText = $(tbSel).val() + ', ';

        // Since we already have the focus, 
        // remove it and set it to another control.
        $('#AdditionalRemarksControl').focus();

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/7903519#7903519
        $(tbSel).val(newText);
        $(tbSel).focus();
        $(tbSel).val($(tbSel).val());
    }">
```

It's working for me successfully in Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 9. Hopefully it works in other browsers, too.

I'm marking Mark's comment as the answer.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: @Randomblue What in particular is misleading to you?

Comment: I want to see it work, ideally in it's simplest form. [Also, I don't understand what `<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender` is.]

Comment: @Randomblue - http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Comment: **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6CyL/1/**. Out of three browsers (Firefox 3.6.23, Opera 11.52, Chromium 14), the code only behaved as expected in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

try to set the scrollLeft property of the input, as:

```
input.scrollLeft = 10000;
```

You can use scrollWidth to get a better guess on the final value, but using a high one can ensure correctness on most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the caret at the end and scroll to the bottom of a textarea, this works perfectly :

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
   setTimeout(function(){
        var pos = $(el).offset().top + $(el).height();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: pos
        }, 1000);
    },100);
}

moveCaretToEnd(document.getElementById("replyBox"));
```

It will place the caret at the end, and then smoothly scroll the window to the bottom.