# jQuery - Place cursor in input field when link clicked

Tags: jquery

I would like to place the cursor in an input field after a specific link is clicked. I'm using this for a small search engine.

Imagine an input field: []. Then some links which is adding a string like: Denmark, England etc. to the input field.

Now I need the cursor to be placed like this: "Denmark, [here]".

Is this possible?

*** UPDATE ***

I'm using this code right now to replace the text, how would you add the "position cursor"-trick with this?

```
$('#denmark').click(function(){     
   $('#searchBoxBig').val('Denmark, ');
});
```

Comment: Do you want multiple clicks to append or replace the text?

Comment: Replace the text.. I've updated the question with the text I use right now

Comment: If you also want to move the caret at the visible part of the browser, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/possible-to-scroll-caret-into-view-inside-a-single-html-text-field-with-javascri/7893633#7893633

Comment: Looks like it's already doing that?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Take it easy dude.. Seriously :-D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set where the cursor is in an input box with the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties. If you don't want any text to be selected, just make them equal to each other.

Here's how you might do it:

```
var input = $("input");
input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = input.val().length;
```

Comment: this did not work on mobile safari for me, had to use the answer of Nicolas Modrzyk.

Answer (score 54):

yes, catch the click event on the anchor prevent the default action and focus on the field.

the function context contains the element that has been clicked so u can compute which field to apply the focus call on.

```
$(anchorSelector).live("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 

   $(fieldSelector).focus();

   return false;
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question, how would you add the trick to my current code, to replace the text?

Comment: This is the way to go!

Comment: Practically and with a new update from Jquery we should go like this 
```$(document).on("click","#go_to_comments", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 

   $("#commentaire").focus()

   return false;
})```

Comment: $(fieldSelector).focus(); is not working

Answer (score 7):

```
$(":input[name=xxxx]").focus();
```

Ah, you need the cursor to be after all the text? Take a look here: [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) it works the same for an input instead of a textarea.

This also works if you use other selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
jQuery('.className').focus();
```

Just use your input filed class name

Comment: What happens if multiple fields use the same class? This should be an ID instead, to ensure that the correct field gets selected.

Comment: we can select with parent class like-       

jQuery('.parentClass .className').focus();