# How to scroll caret into view inside a textbox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, textbox, caret, cursor-position

I need a way of scrolling to the caret position in a textbox **no matter where the caret is**. The problem I am having is very similar to this one:

[Possible to scroll caret into view inside a single HTML text field with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/possible-to-scroll-caret-into-view-inside-a-single-html-text-field-with-javascri)

The solution to the other question I mentioned is given as adding an extra character at the end (which sets the caret position to be at the end of the text) and then simulating a backspace key press (which scrolls to the end of the text). It works fine while the user keeps typing, the text scrolls properly since we are always adding characters to the end of the string. However, if the user, for example, clicks somewhere in the textbox, it sets a new caret position, and if the user then starts typing from the new caret position, the extra key/backspace solution does not work properly as it always takes us to the end of the string.

I need a way of scrolling to the cursor position while the user is typing, no matter where the cursor is. Some more additional information: While using Firefox, setting the textbox value in my Javascript code scrolls to the leftmost position in the textbox although the cursor is at the end. The illustration in [Possible to scroll caret into view inside a single HTML text field with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/possible-to-scroll-caret-into-view-inside-a-single-html-text-field-with-javascri) shows what I mean. It does not happen on IE, Chrome, Safari. So the issue mentioned in this question a problem for me in Firefox only. Any ideas?