# How to make the viewable scope of a text-area cling to the right hand side of the text-area?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a text-area with the following CSS class:

```
.text-area {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;

    height: var(--display-font-size);
    font-size: var(--display-font-size);
    line-height: var(--display-font-size);
    
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

This produces a one line text-area that isn't resizable and has no user-interactive elements. The current output grows as follows as I type from `a` to `z`:

```
|.   abc|
|.  abcd|
|  abcde|
| abcdef|
|abcdef|
|abcdef|g
```

where `|...|` denotes the viewable region of the text area. However, I would like this viewable area to latch onto the right side of the text area so that I produce this effect:

```
|.   abc|
|.  abcd|
|  abcde|
| abcdef|
|abcdef|
a|bcdefg|
```

How might I accomplish this?

Edit:

I've been experimenting with the `<input type="text">` HTML element, but it doesn't solve my problem. I'm not inputting text directly into the textbox; instead I generate a string and place it in the textbox using the value field, so while text may cling to the right side while I type it directly into the box, I can't reproduce this behaviour using my method.

Comment: Seems a lot like you're trying to reinvent the textbox...

Comment: I already get what seems to be your desired effect when I try to recreate this. Actual failing code is always more helpful when debugging than diagrams - please try to share a working example (inline in the question via a stack snippet) of what you have versus what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I've figured out what you're trying to do based on the comments in your edit. You can set the `scrollLeft` property programmatically to keep the cursor right-aligned:

```js
let val = 0;

function setText() {
  const input = document.querySelector('.text-area');
  input.value += " " + val++;
  input.scrollLeft = input.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
.text-area {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;

    height: var(--display-font-size);
    font-size: var(--display-font-size);
    line-height: var(--display-font-size);
    
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="text-area"></textarea>
<button onclick="setText()">Update text</button>
```

Essentially borrowed from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892902/possible-to-scroll-caret-into-view-inside-a-single-html-text-field-with-javascri/7893023) which has some more suggestions.